# How can I use a comparison operator to filter integers in a dictionary that also includes strings as values?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I want to write a code that eliminates int values above a certain threshold while ignoring strings. Currently the code I have throws an error `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. Here is the code:

```
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 'montana' }
number = 2

def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    for k, v in list(dictionary.items()):
        if v > number: 
            del dictionary[k]
return dictionary 



print(remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary))
```

Output should be: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 'montana'}`

Comment: `if type(v) is int and v > number:`

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```py
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 'montana' }
number = 2

newd = {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if type(v) != int or v <= number}
print(newd)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 'montana'}
```

Comment: You should use `isinstance` instead of `type(v) != int`. The later will return `False` for sub-classes but yet, they are valid `int` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try`-`except` or check for the `int` type:

```
# try-except
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    for k, v in list(dictionary.items()):
        try:
            if v > number: 
                del dictionary[k]
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return dictionary 

# Check type
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    for k, v in list(dictionary.items()):
        if isinstance(v, int) and v > number: 
            del dictionary[k]
    return dictionary
```

The function can further be simplified into a dictionary comprehension:

```
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    return {k: v for k,v in dictionary.items() if not(isinstance(v, int) and v > number)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 'montana' }
number = 2
print({k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if not isinstance(v, int) or v <= number})
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 'montana'}
```